# Directly Proving a Set is Closed

Tags: general-topology

Is there a good way to prove that some random closed set is closed using the "contains it's limit points" definition? For instance how could you directly prove the first quadrant with the positive x and y axes is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example, call the quadrant $Q$.

Let a sequence $(x_n,y_n) \subset Q$ converge to $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

We must show that $(x,y) \in Q$.

But $x_n,y_n \geq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ by definition of $Q$. Taking limits as $n \rightarrow \infty$ gives $x,y \geq 0$. So indeed $(x,y) \in Q$.